# Problems in printing array (error scalar value)

Tags: php

I can't find the way to print this array. This is my script:

```
foreach ($task_types as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    $taskqu = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), task_type FROM dotp_tasks WHERE task_type = '$key'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($taskqu)) {
        $taskqu[$row['task_type']] = $row[0];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($taskqu);
echo "</pre>";
```

And when I try to print it, here's the error I get:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try a different variable name for your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing a scalar value with array syntax triggers that warning. For example:

```
$a = 1;
$a[] = 1;
```

Triggers:

> PHP Warning:  Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /Users/darragh/Sites/__.php on line 5

What's the initial value of `$taskqu`? It's clearly not an array, therefore:

```
$taskqu[$row['task_type']] = $row[0];
```

is an invalid operation and raises this PHP warning.

This is because `$taskqu` is already initialised with the return value of `mysql_query`, which (because your query is a `SELECT` statement) is either a [`resource`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) type or `false`.

Either way the value is initialised, is not an array and, as such, cannot be dereferenced with array syntax.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The code does show it: `$taskqu = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), task_type FROM dotp_tasks WHERE task_type = '$key'");`

Comment: THanx ive changed name of $taskqu here to different`$taskqu = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), task_type FROM dotp_tasks WHERE task_type = '$key'");` And it worked :)

Comment: Oh sorry! It's still early :) I somehow missed that. Let me edit that out of the question.

Comment: Updated the answer there so it should be more relevant. And... Glad to hear it worked! :)